# Why didn't Erlang become very popular in distributed applications?

Tags: erlang

I've been learning Erlang recently. Erlang is really powerful for implementing distributed applications.

I think the core advantages of Erlang are:

1. Concurrency-oriented, no locks needed
2. "Let it crash" design philosophy, avoids to do much defensive coding
3. Hot code swapping, application distribution becomes easy

Though there are some projects using Erlang, such as CouchDB, RabbitMQ, etc, but the influence of Erlang is still insignificant, compared with Java/Python. Most people will consider Hadoop/MapReduce when designing distributed application, not Erlang. What's the problem with Erlang?

Comment: I smell subjectivity...but I'm curious :)

Comment: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: @larsks:  One does not mean argue with you over policy!  Like Cheezmeister, though, I am curious.  I like the question.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is best fit for these sorts of questions.

Comment: Thanks, I will move this question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why did PHP become as popular as it is, even though it's arguably a hack? Being in the right place at the right time and appealing to the right crowd is often more important than pure technical merits. As unfortunate as it is. I think this question is hardly objectively answerable.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that Argument is an intellectual process. Contradiction is just the automatic gainsaying of any statement the other person makes.

Comment: Erlang is fairly new as compared to `java` or `python`. Most people in the world are static. After years of investing time to learn a particular language, people find it hard to to the same for a new language. In the future though, Erlang is bound to become most popular

Comment: Real question is why this is the first result in Google for "hadoop erlang" and what can be done to avoid this

Comment: @dan3, +1 for mentioning about Google result.

Comment: Has the question been moved to "programmers“ stack exchange yet?